# Error upon installing SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express but get the error

> set.exe is not a valid Win32 application

I do not have that much disc space on this machine as it is at the moment, only 10,5 gig, is this perhaps the problem? Any advice perhaps on what the cause could be and how to fix it.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a corrupted download.  Instead of [RUN], choose [Save] and then run from your local hard drive.  Verify the size of the download before running the executable.  If this doesn't work, try to download it again.

Make sure you read the system  requirements on MS DL as `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe`: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695)